# Swing buttons to cause label or textfield to change

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java and am trying to get two buttons to change a textfield and a label.  I think the problem is that l in the ClearButton class and tf in the CopyButton class cannot be referenced.  How do I do that?

```
public class SwingEx1  
{
   JFrame f;
   JPanel p;
   JLabel l;
   JTextField tf;
   JButton b1,b2;

   public SwingEx1()
   {
      f = new JFrame("Swing Example");
      p = new JPanel();
      l = new JLabel("Initial Label");
      tf = new JTextField("Enter Text");
      b1 = new JButton("Clear");
      b2 = new JButton("Copy");
   }

   public void LaunchFrame()
   {
      p.add(b1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      p.add(b2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      p.add(l,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      p.add(tf,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      f.getContentPane().add(p);
      b1.addActionListener(new ClearButton());
      b2.addActionListener(new CopyButton());
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      SwingEx1 swObj1 = new SwingEx1();
      swObj1.LaunchFrame();
   }
}

class ClearButton implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
    tf.setText("");
   }
}

class CopyButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
        l.setText(tf.getText());
   }
}
```

Comment: try to use `l.repaint()` after `l.setText()`

Comment: Something that jumped out at me, and I just tested this. You can't have two objects in the same section for BorderLayout. The results of my testing is the first object that was added got over-written by the second object. In otherwords... b1 and l will never appear, because they are getting overwritten by b2 and tf.

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue. You've declared tf inside your SwingEx1 class, so outside classes don't know it exists! I would move your button classes inside the SwingEx1 class, that should make them able to resolve the variable names. class structure would look like this:

```
class SwingEx1 
{
    ...
    class ClearButton implements ActionListener
    {
        ...
    }
    class CopyButton implements ActionListener
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't simply have the class implement ActionListener.  That way you wouldn't have to worry about the scoping issues.  You should also give your variables meaningful names like btnClear, btnCopy.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SwingEx1 implements ActionListener {

    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JLabel l;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton b1, b2;

    public SwingEx1() {
        f = new JFrame("Swing Example");
        p = new JPanel();
        l = new JLabel("Initial Label");
        tf = new JTextField("Enter Text");
        b1 = new JButton("Clear");
        b2 = new JButton("Copy");
    }

    public void LaunchFrame() {
        p.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p.add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p.add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingEx1 swObj1 = new SwingEx1();
        swObj1.LaunchFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            tf.setText("");
        } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            l.setText(tf.getText());
        }
    }
}
```